# Make Sinc'[0] return 0 instead of Indeterminate

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, upvalues

I want Sinc'[0] to return 0, but instead it returns Indeterminate.

I've tried

```
Unprotect[Sinc]
Unprotect[Derivative]
Derivative[1][Sinc][0] ^= 0
```

But it doesn't work.

Maybe this needs to be similar to this (from the help files for Derivative)

```
f'[x_] := If[PossibleZeroQ[x], N[0, Precision[x]], (x Cos[x] - Sin[x])/x^2];
```

Comment: Why not define your own function?

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing if the community considers this a bug

Comment: @Rojo Techinically it's true that the derivative should be Piecewise[{{..., x!=0}, {0, x==0}] but since it's a single point only it's not exactly a unique situation in Mma ...

Comment: @Szabolcs yes. However, that single point is the whole point of having a `Sinc` function in the first place so this itches me a little

Comment: @Rojo I played a bit with piecewise functions and I think I know why this is not feasible: suppose the derivative were returned as a piecewise.  Actually we might as well start from `sinc[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sin[x]/x, x != 0}}, 1]`.  The mathematically proper derivative of `Sinc` should be what `sinc'[x]` returns.  But now let's take the derivative of this once more: `D[sinc'[x],x]`.  This will be a piecewise that's still 0 in the point $x=0$.  However the actual second derivative sinc''(0) should be -1/3.  This illustrates how Piecewise itself is unable to handle derivatives ...

Comment: ... in a mathematically correct way, and it's not difficult to see why.  Since `Piecewise` won't give us proper derivative, it doesn't make a lot of sense to return a piecewise for `Sinc'[x]`.  It would just delay the problem until the next derivative.  OK, this is somewhat subjective, but after thinking this through I start to accept why they might have consciously made the decision not to both with Sinc'[x] in x=0.  My point is that while they could have implemented `Derivative[n][Sinc][x]` to return a correct Piecewise for any `n`, taking another derivative of that result would fail anyway.

Comment: @Szabolcs what about keeping it symbolic until numeric arguments or `FunctionExpand` is applied?

Comment: @Rojo People would complain that "it's not computed".  Maybe it could be forced using `FunctionExpand` ...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70165/derivative-of-sinc-function

Comment: Maybe the mathematicians should give the derivative function a name ( Cosc ? ). Then it would be more satisfying to leave the result in a symbolic form..

Comment: @Rojo Why would you consider this a bug? What symbol should the definition be associated with? As I can see, neither Derivative nor Sinc do not fit into UpValues definition here. Derivative is too up, Sinc is too deep.

Comment: …Sorry, I did not see VF1 had provided the correct UpValues declaration by then. UpValues works with “[0]” omitted, as it should.

Comment: I'm the OP. My version is  8.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (October 10, 2011). Can anyone confirm Sinc'[0] returns Indeterminate in version 9.

Comment: I really don't know. I kinda see the inconsistency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a slightly more robust way to modify the default behavior.  It works for all positive derivatives of `Sinc`:

```
Unprotect[Sinc];
Sinc /: Derivative[n_Integer?Positive][Sinc] := 
   Piecewise[{
     {(-1)^(n/2)/(n + 1), # == 0 && EvenQ[n]}, 
     {0, # == 0 && OddQ[n]}, 
     {Derivative[n - 1][Cos[#]/# - Sin[#]/#^2 &][#], True}
   }] &;
Protect[Sinc];
```

Usage:

```
Sinc'[0]
(* 0 *)


Sinc''[0]
(* -1/3 *)
```

Comment: `Derivative` supports direct assignment without the need to unprotect.  So `Derivative[n_Integer?Positive][Sinc] := ...` is sufficient (without `TagSet` or `Unprotect`).

Comment: @Szabolcs That's true, but the way WRI implements derivatives of built-in special functions is to associate them to the special function with `TagSet`.  See *e.g.* ``<<GeneralUtilities`; PrintDefinitions[PolyLog]; PrintDefinitions[MittagLefflerE]``, *etc..*.  So, I follow the WRI way for `Sinc`.

Answer (score 10):

One solution is making your own function:

```
MySinc[x_] := Sinc[x]
Derivative[1][MySinc] ^= 
  If[# == 0, 0, Derivative[1][Sinc] // Evaluate] &;
MySinc[0]
(* 1 *)
MySinc'[0]
(* 0 *)
```

And then in expressions which use `Sinc` use `expr/.Sinc->MySinc`. To me this seems like the cleanest solution. However, this can be done with `Sinc`, too. But it is difficult to undo!

```
Unprotect[Sinc];
tmp = Derivative[1][Sinc] // Evaluate;
Derivative[1][Sinc] ^= If[# == 0, 0, tmp] &;
Protect[Sinc];
Sinc[0]
(* 1 *)
Sinc'[0]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: I supose i should accept this. It offers 2 good suggestions

Comment: @pdmclean does the latter part not directly answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

The function is:

```
f[x_] = D[Sinc[x], x];
f[x]
Cos[x]/x - Sin[x]/x^2
```

In its current form, the value at `x=0` is indeterminate. It is only when taking the limit as `x->0` that a value emerges. Hence:

```
Limit[D[Sinc[x], x], x -> 0]
0
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
Limit[f[x], x -> 0]
0
```

Comment: I of course agree that you need to take the limit but the same reasoning could be applied to `Sinc` alone. So I agree with @Rojo above that the reason to have a `Sinc` function should be that you don't have to evaluate `Limit[Sin[x]/x,x->0]` every time. It would be nice if the same was true for `Sinc'`.