# Why does MatrixFunction with Sinc return this error?

Tags: functions, matrix, linear-algebra, warning-messages

The following:

```
mat = {{1., -3, -2}, {-1, 3, -2}, {0., 0., 0.}}
MatrixFunction[Sinc, mat]
```

returns:

```
MatrixFunction::drvnnum: Unable to compute the matrix function because 
the subsequent derivative of the function Sinc[#1] & at a numeric value is 
not numeric.
```

The documentation for this error gives examples where the function is not differentiable. But here, `Sinc` is, so why do I get this error?

Comment: Perhaps `Sinc'[0.]` and `Sinc'[x]` give a clue? (The derivative of `Sinc` unfortunately reverts to the derivative of `Sin[x]/x`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I see. But why does `MatrixFunction` requires the derivatives, and not "just" the sum of the ponderated matrix powers?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42159/12

Comment: @anderstood Good question. Please see my contribution.

Comment: @Michael E2 I think my simple regularization is fairly general and easy to implement.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze It seems to be coded to work only on matrices with integer entries (maybe use `Rationalize`?). And it works symbolically instead of numerically. That might be slow on large matrices. It's a nice method (and all methods have plusses and minuses usually).

Comment: @Michael E2: for numerical matrices I have already proposed the partial series approach. Now I have added the regularization approach as well.

Comment: I wish to add a comment but I do not have sufficient reputation to do so. The MATLAB function [`wkm`](https://github.com/nadukandi/wkm) can be used to compute `sinc(A)` as follows: A = [1, -3, -2; -1, 3, -2; 0, 0, 0]; [C, S] = wkm(-A^2);
The matrices `C` and `S` returned by `wkm` are the matrix functions `cos(A)` and `sinc(A)`.

Answer (score 19):

Two things come into play:

1. `Sinc'[0]` yields `Indeterminate`, when it should be $0$.
2. This value needs to be evaluated in the computation of `MatrixFunction[Sinc, mat]`.

In details: for the computation of `MatrixFunction[]` for an inexact matrix $\mathbf A$, a preliminary step is to always perform the [Schur decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchurDecomposition.html) $\mathbf A=\mathbf Q\mathbf T\mathbf Q^\top$ (effectively, a similarity transformation into a triangular matrix). The reason for this is that the computation of a matrix function is easiest when a matrix is triangular.

Here, then is the required Schur decomposition:

```
MatrixForm /@ ({q, t} = SchurDecomposition[mat])
```

[image: Schur factors]

The problem arises in the computation of `MatrixFunction[Sinc, t]`, since as mentioned previously, the evaluation of `Sinc'` at $0$ is needed, as evidenced by the following general formula:

```
MatrixFunction[f, {{0, a, b}, {0, c, d}, {0, 0, 0}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: MatrixFunction evaluation for a special triangle]

A workaround in this case would be to use the explicit piecewise form of `Sinc[]`:

```
mySinc = Piecewise[{{1, # == 0}, {Sin[#]/#, True}}] &;
MatrixFunction[mySinc, mat]
```

[image: sinc of a matrix]

You can check that the result of `q.MatrixFunction[mySinc, t].Transpose[q]` is the same.

However, **this is not robust**. Consider the following evaluation:

```
MatrixFunction[f, {{0, a, b}, {0, 0, d}, {0, 0, 0}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: MatrixFunction evaluation for a defective matrix]

where it can be seen that the *second* derivative is now involved. Neither `Sinc''` nor `mySinc''` will yield the right answer if evaluated on a matrix like this or similar to this, since one function is indeterminate and the other gives $0$ when the correct value should be $-\frac13$. For matrices of larger dimension where even higher derivatives might be involved, this is even more troublesome.

---

### What to do when `MatrixFunction[]` fails?

I've always maintained that one of the nice things about *Mathematica* is that if all else fails, one can always go back to the mathematical definition. The situation is no different for `MatrixFunction[]`; as I have previously mentioned here and in other threads, the function seems to be based on evaluating a given function on a triangular matrix that is similar to the original matrix given to it, generated through either `JordanDecomposition[]` (in the exact case) or `SchurDecomposition[]` (in the inexact case). Since these seem to be failing here, we could use a different definition of the function of a matrix. Luckily, [there are several of them](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2306996).

In particular, one of the most useful definitions of a matrix function is the following Cauchy-like contour integral:

$$f(\mathbf A) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma f(z)\, (z \mathbf I- \mathbf A)^{-1}\,\mathrm dz$$

where $\gamma$ is a closed contour enclosing the eigenvalues of $\mathbf A$, and where $f(z)$ is analytic within. (I previously mentioned this [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92293).)

As it turns out, this definition is useful for both exact and inexact computations. Let's deal with the exact case first, using an exact version of the matrix in the OP:

```
mat = {{1, -3, -2}, {-1, 3, -2}, {0, 0, 0}};
```

A slick way to use the contour integral definition is to recognize that the required computation is equivalent to the sum of the residues of the integrand at the eigenvalues of the original matrix, by virtue of the [residue theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ResidueTheorem.html) and the [Cauchy integral theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralTheorem.html).

Thus, we can compute the supposed result of `MatrixFunction[Sinc, mat]` in this way:

```
Sum[Map[Residue[#, {z, λ}] &, Sinc[z] Inverse[z IdentityMatrix[Length[mat]] - mat], {2}],
    {λ, Union[Eigenvalues[mat]]}]
```

[image: sine cardinal of a matrix]

(Note that `Residue[]` had to be mapped manually, as it does not automatically thread over lists.)

---

To demonstrate the application of the contour integral method to the inexact case, allow me to consider a different matrix and a different function with a removable singularity.

In particular, consider the matrix

```
rm = {{2/3, 0, -2/3, -1/3}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1/3, 0, 2/3, -2/3}, {2/3, 0, 1/3, 2/3}};
```

and suppose that you want to evaluate the function $f(\mathbf A)=(\mathbf A-\mathbf I)^{-1}\log\mathbf A$. The eigenvalues of this matrix are

```
eig = Eigenvalues[rm]
   {(-1)^(1/3), -(-1)^(2/3), 1, 1}
```

and thus, `MatrixFunction[Log[#]/(# - 1) &, rm]` is not expected to work in this case (and neither will `Inverse[]` + `MatrixLog[]`). For numerical evaluation, we use `NIntegrate[]` along with an appropriate choice of contour.

A particularly convenient contour can be obtained by treating the eigenvalues as points in the complex plane, and then slightly dilating the axis-aligned bounding rectangle that contains the eigenvalues. This can be done like so:

```
With[{ε = 1/20}, 
     corners = #1 + I #2 & @@@ Tuples[Transpose[(List @@ 
               BoundingRegion[ReIm[eig], "MinRectangle"]) + {-ε, ε}]][[{2, 1, 3, 4, 2}]]];
```

after which, one can then evaluate the contour integral:

```
NIntegrate[Log[z]/(z - 1) Inverse[z IdentityMatrix[4] - rm],
           {z, Sequence @@ corners} // Evaluate]/(2 π I) // Chop
   {{0.9379331214115499, 0, 0.271266454744782, 0.3333333333333591},
    {0, 1.0000000000001494, 0, 0},
    {-0.3333333333333591, 0, 0.9379331214115499, 0.271266454744782},
    {-0.271266454744782, 0, -0.3333333333333591, 0.9379331214115499}}
```

(Some `NIntegrate::izero` messages are thrown, but these are due to the zero entries and are harmless in this case.)

This compares favorably with the result of the residue-based method:

```
Sum[Map[Residue[#, {z, λ}] &, Log[#]/(# - 1) &[z] Inverse[z IdentityMatrix[4] - rm], {2}],
    {λ, Union[Eigenvalues[rm]]}] // FullSimplify
```

[image: symbolic result]

```
N[%]
   {{0.9379331214114057, 0., 0.2712664547447392, 0.3333333333333333},
    {0., 1., 0., 0.},
    {-0.3333333333333333, 0., 0.9379331214114057, 0.2712664547447392},
    {-0.2712664547447392, 0., -0.3333333333333333, 0.9379331214114057}}
```

---

For people who are interested in further details, I will recommend reading *[Functions of Matrices: Theory and Computation](http://books.google.com/books?id=S6gpNn1JmbgC)* by Nick Higham.

Comment: Would rationalizing be a workaround?

Comment: In that case, the Jordan decomposition is used instead of Schur, but derivatives will still be needed.

Comment: Well, I wish I could upvote again!

Comment: The note of appreciation suffices, @Michael. :)

Comment: An advantage of the contour integral definition that I forgot to mention is that both versions are easily modified to implement the "action form" of a matrix function, $f(\mathbf A)\mathbf x$: one merely replaces the `Inverse[]` with an appropriate call to `LinearSolve[]` on the given vector.

Comment: @J.M. (+1) for exploring the contour integral method of Nicholas J. Higham, hereby bringing the book to our attention.

Comment: @J.M. Very elegant method indeed, but please see my recent EDIT which treats your example easily with the regularization method. I would appreciate to see an example which would lead to a failure.

Comment: @Dr. Hintze, I've seen it, but unfortunately I cannot give a second upvote. I don't forsee any case where the residue method and the regularization method will not both work, as both are implicitly taking limits that should exist if the matrix function is defined on the given matrix.

Comment: @J.M. Here's an example for a function with an essential singularity: Limit[MatrixFunction[1/# Exp[-1/#] &, 
   rm + \[Epsilon] IdentityMatrix[4]], \[Epsilon] -> 
   0] // FullSimplify to be tested with the contour integral method.

Comment: @Dr. Hintze, as a reminder: matrix functions only make sense when the corresponding scalar function is defined on the spectrum (eigenvalues) of the given matrix. In your example, the spectrum is far away from the singularity, so even `MatrixFunction[Exp[-1/#]/# &, rm]` works.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT #2**

The regularization method is more generally applicable than the Cauchy method.

Here's an example for which (according to J.M.) the Cauchy method fails but the regularization method works.

The matrix is that of the OP (integer form)

```
matx = {{1, -3, -2}, {-1, 3, -2}, {0, 0, 0}};

Eigenvalues[matx]

(* Out[90]= {4, 0, 0} *)
```

and the function has an essential singularity at 0. We obatin immediately

```
Limit[MatrixFunction[1/# Exp[-1/#] &, matx + \[Epsilon] IdentityMatrix[3]], \[Epsilon] -> 0] // FullSimplify

(* Out[50]= {{1/(16 E^(1/4)), -(3/(16 E^(1/4))), 1/(16 E^(1/4))}, {-(1/(16 E^(1/4))), 3/(16 E^(1/4)), -(1/(16 E^(1/4)))}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Really simple, and fast.

**EDIT**

J.M.'s example treated with the regularization method

The Matrix:

```
rm = {{2/3, 0, -(2/3), -(1/3)}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1/3, 0, 2/3, -(2/3)}, {2/3, 0, 1/3, 2/3}}
```

The task is to calculate the matrix function

```
MatrixFunction[Log[#]/(# - 1) &, rm]

During evaluation of In[29]:= MatrixFunction::fnand: The function Log[#1]/(#1-1)& is not analytic or defined at 1. >>
```

The direct approach fails.

But regularization makes life easy:

```
MatrixFunction[Log[#]/(# - 1) &, 
  rm + \[Epsilon] IdentityMatrix[4]];

Limit[%, \[Epsilon] -> 0] // FullSimplify

(* Out[33]= {{1/9 (3 + Sqrt[3] \[Pi]), 0, 1/9 (-3 + Sqrt[3] \[Pi]), 1/
  3}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {-(1/3), 0, 1/9 (3 + Sqrt[3] \[Pi]), 
  1/9 (-3 + Sqrt[3] \[Pi])}, {1/9 (3 - Sqrt[3] \[Pi]), 0, -(1/3), 
  1/9 (3 + Sqrt[3] \[Pi])}} *)
```

**Summary**

It may seem that the problem comes from the singularity of the Matrix `mat`, and is naturally related to the problem with `Sin[x]/x/.x->0`. But J.M. showed that problems arise if the matrix is defective.

There is no problem with `MatrixFunction[Sinc, mat1]` if `Det[mat1] != 0`.

We shall proceed here without exploring the root cause and show that the `MatrixFunction` of the OP can be computed exactly using two methods (a) power series, and (b) regularization, with the result:

```
MatrixFunction[Sinc, mat] ==
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{16} (\sin (4)+12) & \frac{1}{16} (-3) (\sin (4)-4) & \frac{1}{16} (\sin (4)-4) \\
 \frac{1}{16} (4-\sin (4)) & \frac{1}{16} (3 \sin (4)+4) & \frac{1}{16} (4-\sin (4)) \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

**Derivation**

*Power series*

We shall calculate the matrix function by a power series. This requires nothing but the powers of the matrix which always exist for a square matrix.

Here is the power series of `Sinc[]`:

```
Sum[(-1)^k x^(2 k)/(2 k + 1)!, {k, 0, ∞}]

(* Out[10]= Sin[x]/x *)
```

The matrix in question is

```
mat = {{1., -3, -2}, {-1, 3, -2}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`}} 

(* Out[9]= {{1., -3, -2}, {-1, 3, -2}, {0., 0., 0.}} *)
```

In order to calculate the powers symbolically we take numerical constants and define

```
mat1 = Floor[mat]

(* Out[11]= {{1, -3, -2}, {-1, 3, -2}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```

From the first few even powers we can easily guess the general form:

```
mp[k_] := {{4^(2 k - 1), -3 4^(2 k - 1), 4^(2 k - 1)}, {-4^(2 k - 1), 
    3 4^(2 k - 1), -4^(2 k - 1)}, {0, 0, 0}};
```

Notice that, due to the singularity of mat1, the zeroth power does not exist.

```
MatrixPower[mat1, 0]
```

> During evaluation of In[15]:= MatrixPower::sing: Matrix
>   {{1,-3,-2},{-1,3,-2},{0,0,0}} is singular. >>

```
(* Out[15]= MatrixPower[{{1, -3, -2}, {-1, 3, -2}, {0, 0, 0}}, 0] *)
```

Hence we take care of the zeroth power by simply adding the unit matrix.
We find finally

```
f = DiagonalMatrix[Array[1 &, 3]] + 
  Sum[(-1)^k mp[k]/(2 k + 1)!, {k, 1, ∞}]

(* Out[46]= {{1 + 1/16 (-4 + Sin[4]), -(3/16) (-4 + Sin[4]), 
  1/16 (-4 + Sin[4])}, {1/16 (4 - Sin[4]), 1 + 3/16 (-4 + Sin[4]), 
  1/16 (4 - Sin[4])}, {0, 0, 1}} *)
```

*Regularization*

If we make the matrix into a regular one by adding a small matrix

```
mat2 = mat1 + ε DiagonalMatrix[Array[1 &, 3]];

Det[mat2]

(* Out[48]= ε (4 ε + ε^2) *)
```

we can apply the MatrixFunction without any problem:

```
f2 = MatrixFunction[Sinc, mat2];
```

and then take the limit

```
f20 = Limit[f2, ε -> 0];
```

This gives the same result as before

```
f == f20

(* Out[52]= True *)
```

*Numerical matrix, partial series*

Defining the partial series as

```
fn[nn_] := 
 DiagonalMatrix[Array[1 &, 3]] + 
  Sum[(-1)^k MatrixPower[mat, 2 k]/(2 k + 1)!, {k, 1, nn}]
```

we can calculate the numerical result up to the nn-th term.

For `nn = 8` the result is alrady we find

```
fn[8] // N

(* Out[64]= {{0.7027, 0.8919, -0.2973}, {0.2973, 0.1081, 0.2973}, {0., 0., 1.}} *)
```

in fair agreement with the exact values:

```
f // N

(* Out[65]= {{0.7027, 0.8919, -0.2973}, {0.2973, 0.1081, 0.2973}, {0., 0., 1.}} *)
```

*Numerical matrix, regularization*

Regularizing the numerical matrix of the OP gives

```
mat4 = mat + ε DiagonalMatrix[Array[1 &, 3]];
```

Application of `MatrixFunction` with given small `ε`

```
f4 = MatrixFunction[Sinc, mat4] /. ε -> 10^(-8)
```

> During evaluation of In[96]:= JordanDecomposition::jdimp: Unable to
>   find the Jordan decomposition of the matrix with the given precision.
>   Try higher precision or SchurDecomposition instead. >>

```
(* Out[96]= {{0.7027, 0.8919, -0.2973}, {0.2973, 0.1081, 0.2973}, {0., 0., 1.}} *)
```

results in the known numerical result despite of the error message.

*Examples of singular matrices*

An extreme case of a matrix is

```
mat3 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
```

Nevertheless, there's no problem with Sinc:

```
MatrixFunction[Sinc, mat3]

(* Out[73]= {{1, 0}, {0, 1}} *)
```

Matrices of the type {{a,b},{0,0}} with a,b [Element]{0,1}

```
mm = {#, {0, 0}} & /@ Union[Tuples[{1, 0, 0, 0}, 2]]

(* Out[15]= {{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 0}}} *)

Table[{k, MatrixFunction[Sinc, mm[[k]]]}, {k, 1, 4}]

During evaluation of In[18]:= MatrixFunction::fnanc: The function Sinc[#1]& is not analytic at 0. >>

(* Out[18]= {
{1, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, 
{2, MatrixFunction[inc, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}]}, 
{3, {{Sinc[1], 0}, {0, 1}}}, 
{4, {{Sinc[1], -1 + Sinc[1]}, {0, 1}}}
} *)
```

Notice that only for mm[[2]] Mathematica complains the presumed non-analyticity of Sinc at 0 and Returns the input unevaluated.

Again the **regularization method** removes the problem:

```
meps = \[Epsilon] IdentityMatrix[2];

Table[{k, MatrixFunction[Sinc, meps + mm[[k]]]}, {k, 1, 4}];

Limit[%, \[Epsilon] -> 0]

(* Out[21]= {{1, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, {2, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, {3, {{Sin[1], 0}, {0, 1}}}, {4, {{Sin[1], -1 + Sin[1]}, {0, 1}}}} *)
```

Comment: "from the singularity of the Matrix" - it's not necessarily due to singularity. For example, `MatrixFunction[Sinc, {{2, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]` evaluates without a hitch. It's when the matrix is *defective* that we get into trouble with `Sinc`'s derivatives.

Comment: @J.M. Good counterexample to my first statement. Do you also have one for the case Det[mat]!=0 an still difficulties with Sinc? I think it is always possible to calculate the matrix function by a power series, if applicable. That's what I did here to find the result for the specific mat.

Comment: If there are no zero eigenvalues (thus, nonsingular), then there isn't any trouble with `Sinc[]` and its derivatives. Yes, power series are one way to evaluate matrix functions when the Schur-Parlett algorithm is not usable, but there are also [other ways](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2306996).

Comment: BTW: `IdentityMatrix[]` is built-in, so you can do `IdentityMatrix[3]` instead of `DiagonalMatrix[Array[1 &, 3]]`. For your last example, I would consider `{{0, 1}, {0, 0}}` to be the simplest example of a matrix whose `Sinc[]` can't be evaluated.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. (1) IdentityMatrix[] I once knew it ... -) (2) I have added some more examples, including yours, and also showed that regularization removes the analyticity problem with it.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a workaround I've used for `Sinc`. It defines `mySinc[k, x]` to be the k-th derivative of `Sinc[x]`, for `k` a nonnegative integer. (*Update notice:* Thanks to J.M. for pointing out a simple formula for the derivatives at zero.)

```
ClearAll[mySinc];
SetAttributes[mySinc, NHoldFirst];
mySinc[x_] := mySinc[0, x];
mySinc[0, x_?NumericQ] := Sinc[x];
mySinc[k_Integer?Positive, 0.] := N[(-1)^k Cos[k π/2]/(k + 1)];
mySinc[k_Integer?Positive, x_] /; x == 0 := 
  SetAccuracy[(-1)^k Cos[k π/2]/(k + 1),
   Piecewise[{{Log10[2 (k + 3)] + 2 Accuracy[x], EvenQ[k]}}, Log10[k + 2] + Accuracy[x]]];
mySinc[k_Integer?Positive, x_?NumericQ] /; x != 0 := 
  Evaluate@D[(# Cos[#] - Sin[#])/#^2, {#, k - 1}] &@x;
Derivative[n_Integer?Positive][mySinc][x_] := mySinc[n, x];
Derivative[0, n_Integer?Positive][mySinc][k_, x_] := mySinc[k + n, x];
```

Examples:

```
MatrixFunction[mySinc, mat] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MatrixFunction[mySinc, Round@mat] // Simplify // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

*Caveat:*
The derivatives of `Sinc` are not numerically well-behaved near zero.

```
Labeled[
 TableForm[
  Table[SetPrecision[
    100 - Precision@Derivative[k][Sinc][SetPrecision[x, 100]],
    3], {x, 10^-Range[8]}, {k, 7}],
  TableHeadings -> {"10"^Row[{"-", #}] & /@ Range[8], Automatic}],
 {"x", "Derivative"}, {Left, Top}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> *Precision loss of $\hbox{Sinc}^{(k)}(x)$ for $x$ near $0$.*

The loss seems fairly predictable, and one could modify the definitions above to use sufficient precision internally to compute a result to a desired precision.

Comment: Here's a slightly simpler expression: `mySinc[k_Integer?Positive, 0.] := N[(-1)^k Cos[k π/2]/(k + 1)]`

Comment: @J.M. Thanks! I did think of something like that, but I didn't think of using in `mySinc[.., 0.]`.  Strange, them blind spots.

Comment: You might also be interested in this explicit formula: `mySinc[k_Integer?Positive, x_?NumericQ] /; x != 0 := Sum[(-1)^j x^(-j - 1) j! Binomial[k, j] Sin[x + (k - j) π/2], {j, 0, k}]`.